# Can a case with front USB ports be connected and used as a USB 3.0 port

Tags: usb-3, usb-2

I found this when I typed in my question.  It sort of answers my question but I want to double check.

[Will cases with front USB port support USB 3.0?](https://superuser.com/questions/111961/will-cases-with-front-usb-port-support-usb-3-0)

I have a [Rosewill Challenger](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811147153) case purchased in 2009.  The details only show front usb ports.  I would like to install a USB 3.0 card with an internal port to get USB 3.0 functionality in the front.

Do I need to upgrade the front ports or is the hardware requirements the same for USB 2 and USB 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although they will be physically interchangeable with older versions, USB 3.0 uses a different cable and connector.  Check out this [article](http://www.maximumpc.com/article/features/everything_you_need_know_about_usb_30_plus_first_spliced_cable_photos).  You will not be able to get 3.0 speeds out of your existing front ports on your case.  Im not stating it is impossible to change out your front ports, but more than likely they will not be able to be replaced.  Check with Rosewill support to see if the front USB ports are removable/replaceable.

Comment: Thanks.  That article explained a lot.  I have just sent Rosewill an email seeing if I can purchsae the Challenger U3 front bezel since the cases are similar.

Comment: Rosewill support emailed me back and they do not sell parts only complete products.  Looks like I will have to buy a new case to do what I want.

Comment: I dont know what you "want" as you never described it.  Are you aware of these:  http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=usb+3.0+drive+bay&hl=en&safe=off&prmd=imvns&resnum=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.&biw=1680&bih=949&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=1758689372626080926&sa=X&ei=GOxvTpmYLIrrgQfY4IiNBQ&ved=0CI0BEPMCMAI

Comment: I was hoping I could purchase the front case assembly from Rosewill but they do not do that.  Thanks for the link though.